# Passing a std::unique_ptr as a void* parameter to a function (CPtrArray::Add)

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, unique-ptr, code-analysis

My code:

```
void CAssignSelectedColumnDlg::AddColumnData(CString strHeading, CStringArray* pAryStrNames, int iColumnIndex, int iCustomIndex /*-1*/, BOOL bFixedCustomType /*FALSE*/)
{
    //COLUMN_DATA_S *psData = nullptr;
    //psData = new COLUMN_DATA_S;

    auto psData = std::make_unique<COLUMN_DATA_S>();
    if (psData != nullptr)
    {
        // Note: we don't "own" pAryStrNames

        psData->strHeading = strHeading;
        psData->pAryStrNames = pAryStrNames;
        psData->sActionListInfo.byColumnIndex = iColumnIndex;
        psData->sActionListInfo.byCustomIndex = iCustomIndex;
        psData->sActionListInfo.bFixedCustomType = bFixedCustomType ? true : false;

        m_aryPtrColumnData.Add(psData);
    }
}
```

Code analysis was suggesting I use `std::make_unique` instead of `new`. So I adjusted teh code but now get a compile error. I tried to find a suitable approach:

[image]

> No suitable conversion function from `std::unique_ptr<COLUMN_DATA_S>, std::default_delete<COLUMN_DATA_S>>` to `void *` exists.

The function in question is [`CPtrArray::Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cobarray-class?view=msvc-160#add). I am still trying to gras the smart pointers and their usage in a context like this.

---

Note that we should not be deleting the pointer when the function ends. The deletion of the collection is done in a dialog event handler.

Comment: *Note that we should not be deleting the pointer when the function ends.* Then you can't use a `std::unique_ptr` as you are trying to do. Maybe a `std::shared_ptr`, but that just gets messy. You'll need to work with the embedded raw pointer (the `.get()` function of the smart pointers gives you that) in all your interactions with MFC and the WinAPI.

Comment: @AdrianMole So this is a classic case of using that pragma approach you referred to to suppres it. I wish that was a click of a button to insert. :)

Comment: Use [`unique_ptr::release()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release) to transfer ownership of the pointer from the smart pointer to the `CPtrArray`, i.e. `m_aryPtrColumnData.Add(psData.release())`. The documentation doesn't say how `Add()` reports errors, so there may still be an opportunity to leak memory.

Comment: @IInspectable That works great!